# Stack Overflow Portuguese Features

Tags: support, unicode, portuguese-stackoverflow

The new [*Stack Overflow em Português*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) beta site is on.

It supports international characters in tags, it looks like the whole site is optimized for high-resolution displays. Maybe there are even more new features.

What are the new features of the Portuguese beta site and which ones will make it into SO?

Comment: "hole site"? funny! ;)

Comment: unicode tags is an old feature that is simply not enabled on most sites

Comment: @AlienArrays: Brazil for instance. [There is a map](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/ola-mundo-announcing-stack-overflow-in-portuguese/?cb=1). And you have to start with one language using international coding. Other Area51 proposals are already waiting for this site to be working like a Chinese site.